# Edge mediaDevices invalid argument

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, mediadevices

I am getting this odd error when I try to get mediaDevices on Edge.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
}).then(function (stream) {
    this.gotStream(stream);
}.bind(this)).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert('Vi kunne ikke få fat i din microfon. Hvis du kom til at svare nej til popupen ryd venligst din browsers cache og prøv igen!');
});
```

[image]

This happens in the `catch` block. What can I try to resolve it?

Comment: It is so strange. I've tested your code on my side. But my error seems different from yours.https://i.stack.imgur.com/KecQN.jpg Is this because you have extra code in your page?

Comment: your comment made me laugh at 1:00 am .. thanks for that !!!!! cheers